How can I scale my image resolution to a different size in Krita?
In Microsoft Paint, I can simply press Ctrl+W to bring up the "Resize and Skew" popup to increase the resolution of my image. This is how that window looks in Microsoft Paint:
 
How can I do this using Krita?
I simply want to take my image and exactly double the resolution/pixels horizontally and vertically for my image.

As stated in the manual, you should use "Scale Image to New Size…" which you can also bring up using Ctrl+Alt+I and change the settings on this dialog:


@JohnMiller the question was only about resizing the image, not exporting. But if you want to resize to export, https://docs.krita.org/en/tutorials/saving-for-the-web.html

To scale your image resolution to a different size in Krita:

Go to Image > Scale Image.
Enter the desired dimensions and resolution.
Click OK to apply the changes.

